# Change album title and genre using additional command-line in Exact Audio Copy

Tags: command-line, exact-audio-copy

The version of my Exact Audio copy is V1.3

I'm trying to change the genre and album title of the CD track using the additional command-line in Extact Audio Copy, but I'm not succeeding.

1 - Original command:

```
-b320 --id3v2-only --pad-id3v2 -ms --tg "%genre%" --tl "%albumtitle%" %source% %dest%"
```

2 - Command to change genre and album title:

```
-b320 --id3v2-only --pad-id3v2 -ms --tg "Classic MPB" --tl "CMG Classic MPB" %source% %dest%""
```

Can I change the genre and album title using commad-line options?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked

```
-b320 --id3v2-only --pad-id3v2 -ms --tg "Classic MPB" --tl "CMG Classic MPB" %source% %dest%
```

The problem is in the two double quotes at the end of the command, I removed the two double quotes and it worked correctly.